# scientific computing problem, error analysis and writing algorithm

Tags: algorithms, error-propagation

For $f(x)=(1-\cos(x))/x^2$,

(a) Analytically evaluate $\lim_{x→0} f(x) = L$.

(b) As $x→0$, at what rate does $f(x)→L$?

(c) Suppose that we are able to represent floating point numbers with $N$ decimal digits of accuracy. Around what value of $r$ will the evaluation of $f(x)$ produce very large relative error when $|x| < r$?

(d) Create your own algorithm or expression for computing $f(x)$ for very small values of $x$. Verify the success of your algorithm computationally.

I know $f(x)$ goes to $1/2$ as $x$ approaches to zero, but i really have no idea how to deal with part b,c and d.

Comment: Are you sure you have this right?        $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (1 - \frac{\cos{x}}{x^2})$ doesn't exist.

Comment: To make it seem more sensible I read it as $(1-\cos x)/x^2$, consistent with the statement that $f(x)$ goes to $1/2$.  I have made an edit to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

(b) We have
\begin{equation}
\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + O(x^6)
\end{equation}
from which it follows that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{x^2}{24} + O(x^4).
\end{equation}
Therefore 
\begin{equation}
f(x) - \frac{1}{2} = O(x^2).
\end{equation}
(c) When $x \rightarrow 0$, $x \not = 0$ the expression $1 - \cos(x)$ will cancel catastrophically. In general, a subtraction $d = a - b$ between two *real* numbers $a$ and $b$ will cancel catastropically when $a \approx b$. Specifically, if $\hat{a} = a(1+\theta_a)$ and $\hat{b} = b(1+\theta_b)$ are the computed approximations for numbers $a$ and $b$, then the difference $\hat{d} = \hat{a} - \hat{b}$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\frac{d - \hat{d}}{d} = \frac{b \theta_b - a \theta_a}{a - b}
\end{equation}
from which it follows that
\begin{equation}
\left | \frac{d - \hat{d}}{d} \right | \leq \frac{|a| + |b|}{|a-b|} \max \{|\theta_a, |\theta_b| \}.
\end{equation}
We see that if $a \approx b$, then the right hand side is not necessarily small. This does not preclude that computed difference $\hat{d}$ will occasionally approximate $d$ with a small relative error, but in general this is not the case and the subtraction will produce garbage. On the other hand, if say $|a| > 2 |b|$, then the subtraction is completely safe, as
\begin{equation}
\frac{|a| + |b|}{|a-b|} \leq \frac{|a| + \frac{1}{2}|a|}{\frac{1}{2}|a|} \leq 3
\end{equation}
which implies that relative error in the subtraction is only a modest (3) multiple of the largest relative error associated with $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$. Returning to the specific problem at hand, then the subtraction $1 - \cos(x)$ is completely safe as long as $1 > 2 \cos(x)$, i.e. as long as
\begin{equation}
|x| \geq \frac{\pi}{3}.
\end{equation}
Inside the interval $I = \left(-\frac{\pi}{3},-\frac{\pi}{3} \right)$ the original expression becomes increasingly useless as $x$ tends to zero. You can therefore defend the choice $r = \frac{\pi}{3}$ as the turning point, regardless of the architecture used.

Now, suppose that we are able to represent floating point numbers with $N$ decimal digits of accuracy. Around what value of $r$ will the evaluation of $f$ produce very large relative errors?

Since
\begin{equation}
\cos(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + O(x^4)
\end{equation}
then we can say with certainty that the floating point representation of $\cos(x)$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
\text{fl}(\cos(x)) = 1,
\end{equation}
when 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} x^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} u,
\end{equation}
where $u$ is the unit round off error on the machine. It follows that any machine should return $\cos(x) = 1$ when $|x| \leq \sqrt{u}$, resulting in a relative error of $1$ for the naive evaluation of $f$. It is possible to be more precise, but then the original question should have included information about the quality of the machine implementation of $\cos$ and a threshold tolerance should have been specified. My best guess is the original author of the problem operated with $u = \frac{1}{2} 10^{-N}$.

(d) In order to evaluate $f(x)$ for small values of $x$ we require an equivalent expression which is reliable. Suppose we desire a relative error which is less than a user specified tolerance $\tau$ inside of the problematic interval $I$. Then we proceed as follows. Let $p_n$ denote the Taylor polynomial or order $n$ for $g(x) = \cos(x)$ at the point $x_0 - 0$. Then
\begin{equation}
p_{2n}(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^{2j} \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}
\end{equation}
and also $p_{2n} = p_{2n+1}$. Then by Taylor's theorem
\begin{equation}
g(x) - p_{2n}(x) = \frac{g^{2n+2}(\xi)}{(2n+2)!} x^{2n+2}
\end{equation}
for at least on $\xi$ between $x$ and $0$. It follows, that
\begin{equation}
\left| f(x) - \frac{1 - p_{2n}(x)}{x^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{(2n+2)!} |x|^{2n} \leq  \frac{1}{(2n+2)!} \left| \frac{\pi}{3} \right|^{2n}. 
\end{equation}
It is now straight forward to select $n$ so that we have a small absolute error. A small relative error can be secured by observing that the target value, i.e $f(x)$ satisfies $|f(x)| \geq \frac{1}{4}$ for all $x \in I$. The relative error satisfies
\begin{equation}
\left| \frac{f(x) - \frac{1 - p_{2n}(x)}{x^2}}{f(x)} \right| \leq \frac{4}{(2n+2)!} \left( \frac{\pi}{3} \right)^{2n} \leq \tau
\end{equation}
provide that $n$ is chosen sufficiently large. If $\tau = 2^{-53}$ is the double precision round off error, then $n=9$ will suffice, but extra care is required during the evaluation of the polynomial as we are operating at the boundaries of machine precision. If $\tau \approx 100u$, then it is certainly safe to apply Horner's method to evaluate the polynomial.

Comment: A very nice answer.  I hope you realize, though, that you completely did this guy's homework for him for free.

Comment: Thank you very much. I struggled with the homework aspect of this problem and I also felt that the original author should have phased part (c) differently. In the end I opted for this extended version, but added three "tripwires" to the answer which will alert the teacher to the fact that the student had help. If the OP rewrites the answer in his own words, then it is likely that he learns what the teacher wanted him to learn and all is well.